# How to find the commit(s) that point to a git tree object?

Tags: git

In trying to mirror a repo to a remote server, the server is rejecting tree object 4e8f805dd45088219b5662bd3d434eb4c5428ec0. This is not a top-level tree, by the way but a subdirectory.

How can I find out which commit(s) indirectly reference that tree object so I can avoid pushing the refs that link to those commits in order to get all the rest of my repo to push properly?

Comment: I've considered deleting the tree object then running `git fsck` hoping it would remove all references to it as part of recovery. But I don't know how to delete an object from a packfile either.

Comment: How about finessing the problem: Use "git bisect" to find the commit that introduced the bad tree reference, and then you can git ls-tree that commit to find the bad tree.

Comment: @RaymondChen That might not work. Besides taking so long (bisect is awesome, but not so much on a tree this large) it may fail because the tree itself may fail to checkout on the relevant commit. Also, I need a "good" and a "bad" sample commit for bisect to get started, and I don't know which commit is bad.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you noted, you just need to find the commit(s) with the desired `tree`.  If it could be a *top level* tree you would need one extra test, but since it's not, you don't.

You want:

- for some set of commits (all those reachable from a given branch name, for instance)
- if that commit has, as a sub-tree, the target tree hash: print the commit ID

which is trivial with two Git "plumbing" commands plus `grep`.

Here's a slightly updated version of my original script (updated to take arguments, and default to `--all` as in [badp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp)'s edit):

```
#! /bin/sh
#
case $# in
0) echo "usage: git-searchfor <object-id> [<starting commit>...]" 1>&2; exit 1;;
esac

searchfor=$(git rev-parse --verify "$1") || exit 1
searchfor=$(git rev-parse --verify "$searchfor"^{tree}) || exit 1
shift
  
git log ${@-"--all"} --pretty='format:%H' |
    while read commithash; do
        if git ls-tree -d -r --full-tree $commithash | grep $searchfor; then
            echo " -- found at $commithash"
        fi
    done
```

To check top-level trees you would `git cat-file -p $commithash` as well and see if it has the hash in it.

Note that this same code will find blobs (assuming you take out the `-d` option from `git ls-tree`).  However, no tree can have the ID of a blob, or vice versa.  The `grep` will print the matching line so you'll see, e.g.:

```
040000 tree a3a6276bba360af74985afa8d79cfb4dfc33e337    perl/Git/SVN/Memoize
 -- found at 3ab228137f980ff72dbdf5064a877d07bec76df9
```

To clean this up for general use, you might want to use `git cat-file -t` on the search-for blob-or-tree to get its type.

As [jthill notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088069/how-to-find-the-commits-that-point-to-a-git-tree-object/41090798?noredirect=1#comment131018599_41090798), `git diff-tree` now has a `--find-object` option.  This was introduced in Git 2.17 (released in 2018, well after the original question here).  The `git log` command has this as well, but we're usually more interested in *which specific commit added* a file or tree.  By removing the extra line that tries to force the `searchfor` hash ID to be a tree, we can get a much faster script that finds either every occurrence of any tree or blob object (though you must take care to specify the correct hash ID or use the `^{tree}` suffix yourself if you're going to supply a commit hash ID).  Then we just run:

```
git log --all --find-object=$searchfor
```

or, as in the comment below:

```
git rev-list --all | git diff-tree --stdin --find-object=$searchfor
```

to find what we're looking for.  (Add `${2-"--all"}` if/as desired.)

Comment: Thanks! This should work, albeit since I don't know which branch/tag has the bad tree, I'd have to run the whole thing in a loop over each one of my several thousand branches (it's a big repo with lots of users). So I'll have to craft some way to get a list of every single commit in the repo across branches and eliminate duplicates first. But this is a great start.

Comment: It looks like `git rev-list` returns a set of commits for any number of refs. And it takes `--stdin` as a parameter. So I can do `git branch -r | git rev-list --stdin` and otherwise keep using your script. :)
Except `git branch` adds whitespace in front of each branch name, which `git rev-list` doesn't like, so I wrote to a file, cleaned it up, then piped it into your script. Now it's very busy searching.

Comment: I was even able to change `origin/master` to `^origin/master` to greatly cut down the number of commits since I know that the tree in question isn't anywhere on the master branch.

Comment: `git rev-list` takes the *same* arguments as `git log`. In fact, they're basically the same command! They are built from one source file that just changes the default settings when run as `git log` vs `git rev-list`. Rev-list is intended for use in scripts, though, while log is intended for use by humans. In any case `A..B` "means" `B ^A` so `origin/master..master` and `master ^origin/master` are exactly the same thing here. In this case you can use `git rev-list --branches ^origin/master` (or maybe `--branches --tags`).

Comment: So, it worked! I did find that the script subtly would only find trees that are subdirectories of the current one (as opposed to starting at the root). I had fixed that, but then it took so long to complete, and I had a pretty good idea of which directory the tree represented so I took advantage of that as an optimization. I got several commits now to work with. :)

Comment: Oh, right, `git ls-tree` likes to start from your current subdirectory (not sure why) and we need `--full-tree` to prevent that.

Comment: faster: `git rev-list --all | git diff-tree --stdin --find-object=4e8f805dd45088219b5662bd3d434eb4c5428ec0` to find all commits introducing that tree, then `git branch --contains` those commits to avoid pushing anything with it.

Comment: @jthill Right, `--find-object` (new in Git 2.17) is now the way to go. I'll tweak the answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Variation of [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41090798/565857) by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in case you want to speed things up via [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
#!/bin/bash    
searchfor="$1"
startpoints="${2-HEAD}"

git rev-list "$startpoints" |
    parallel "if git ls-tree -d -r --full-tree '{}' | grep '$searchfor'; then echo ' -- found at {}'; fi"
```