# fatal: bad tree object. Is manual recreation of the missing tree the only option in this case?

Tags: git

I've been work on this project locally from the late December of 2018.
Now decided to push it to the remote on Github.
When I ran `git push -u <REMOTE_NAME> master` I got the message:

```
fatal: bad tree object c6117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to <REMOTE_URL>
```

Then after a bit research I ran `git fsck`

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 2e4901579b09704ecb89e685630136bf3f217bd3
              to    tree c6117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d

..... A lot of dangling blobs and commits .....

missing tree c6117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d
```

I've navigated to the `.git/с6` and didn't find a file with the name `117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d`
Also had a backup of the project like a one month old. No such file there. 
I had no idea you should manually backup git folder.

Then I ran `git cat-file -p 2e4901579b09704ecb89e685630136bf3f217bd3`. The tree with the broken link to the missing tree. Got this.

```
040000 tree c6117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d    players
```

Then somehow in the Github Desktop I've found two commits related with the missing tree. It turns out that this is a very old commits, from Dec 28 2018.

[image]

Fetched the SHA1 of these commits - `063babbd79d62bfc579b888b944047be6c79cb6d` and `bc64df9f9f734dd3450c2bef240381538cc23d6c`

Then ran `git cat-file -p 063babbd79d62bfc579b888b944047be6c79cb6d`

```
tree 06d7866339756b512bd6129667a33f8c38d464c0
parent 4be4f9a68440aeedd15e56f0a0ff03ed33100753
author <NAME> 1546007706 +0300
committer <NAME> 1546007706 +0300

<FULL COMMIT MESSAGE>
```

Then the same command for other commit. Got the same structure. With different tree and parent

```
tree 07a5f4aeff3b6dc1707720c0701727864152b817
parent 063babbd79d62bfc579b888b944047be6c79cb6d
```

Never got this problem when committing locally. Comes up only when I was trying to push to the remote. 
Problem with missing tree could be related with the fact that I've stored the project in [Yandex.Disk](https://disk.yandex.com/?ncrnd=6950) folder. To synchronize between two PC's. Just moved the project out of that folder.

It looks like the only option to not lose all commits history from Dec 28 is a manual recreation of the missing tree. Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790681/what-is-the-internal-format-of-a-git-tree-object/21599232#21599232). Is it so? Now I doesn't really sure what to put in the missing tree contents. How to figure out which blobs should be there?

Some other related answers that I found useful during the research:

[How can I repair a git repository with a missing object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347796/how-can-i-repair-a-git-repository-with-a-missing-object/8348156#8348156)

[Git: "Corrupt loose object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object/4263009#4263009)

[How to fix git error broken link from tree to tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876512/how-to-fix-git-error-broken-link-from-tree-to-tree/38598015#38598015)

[How to fix a bad git tree object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005756/how-to-fix-a-bad-git-tree-object/9006458#9006458)

[Git recovery: "object file is empty". How to recreate trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797978/git-recovery-object-file-is-empty-how-to-recreate-trees/14871420#14871420)

[Listing all commits given a tree hash id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188545/listing-all-commits-given-a-tree-hash-id/48189814#48189814)

[How to find the commit(s) that point to a git tree object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088069/how-to-find-the-commits-that-point-to-a-git-tree-object/41090798#41090798)

Comment: Reconstructing a missing tree object is exceedingly hard unless you know **exactly** what was in it. You need to construct a tree object that hashes to the original value, otherwise it will fail fsck again, just with a different error message.

Comment: And yes, never use file/folder synchronization tools like Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, Jottacloud, or similar, to synchronize git repositories. It will work until it (catastrophically) doesn't. Instead, use github for synchronization. A little late, I know, but know this for the future, and if you're synchronizing other repositories this same way, **stop doing this right now and start using github** or it will just be a matter of time before you have problems in those repositories as well.

Comment: Can you try to see if you have any in the .git folder that has a name that *contains* 117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d ? (note that I removed the first two characters from the hash since those are used to create folders to keep the files-per-folder ratio lower). Since I don't know if you're using linux, macos or Windows or whatnot I'm unable to provide the right command for you, but do a recursive file search. If Yandex handles duplicates, it might've renamed the file.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, I'm on Windows. Yes, I've decided to move out from Yandex even before I've discovered the problem.

Comment: Then try `dir *117da288c2323cdb4d695dcd7cdfa6f1c0118d*.* /s` inside the .git folder, and see if it finds anything.

Comment: No luck, [screen](https://yadi.sk/i/COIEeVpG_5NC5Q)

Comment: I don't know what you should do then, sorry.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, probably should just scratch all of the commits and live with it.

Comment: In all honesty, if I were in your situation I would probably just commit whatever history is there to github. Also I would ZIP the existing broken repo and keep it forever locally, in case you really at some point in future need some 1 year old changes in a particular subtree.

Comment: Yes, if this was me, I would do what @sbat said. I would zip the current repository, with the problem, tuck it away, then create a fresh repository and commit whatever history would be needed to create the branches needed for ongoing work. I think you'll find that satisfying fsck in this case will be exceedingly hard.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen,  btw, is this a normal behavior for git, I mean, allowing to commit locally if repo is really broken? It's running `fsck` automatically before pushing to the remote?

Comment: I don't know the heuristics of when it runs fsck. I could imagine it would happen when dealing with packfiles, though I'm not sure. A full fsck is not done on commit, however, and obviously not on every push or you would never have been able to push to github in the first place. TL;DR: Have no idea, but apparently it doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: @sbat, I've decided to go with you solution, you can post this as an answer.

Comment: @edvard_munch well, my comment is not really a solution! :) Let's keep the question open, maybe someone will come up with better answer on how to restore individual broken commit safely (like remove it or something like this). Good luck with a project!